# Merging two data sets based on intervals

Tags: merge

I was wondering how I can merge these two data sets by a and b. `a` column in f data set is the lower bound of the intervals so I need to merge 1.5 from g data set with 1 from f, 4.4 from g with 4 from f, 9.8 from g with 9 from f and etc.

```
a<-seq(1:10)
b<-c("a","b","a","b","a","a","a","b","b","a")
f<-data.frame(a,b)

a<-c(1.5,1.4,2.3,2.2,4.4,4,5,6.6,9.8,4.1,4.6,5.5)
b<-c("a","b","b","b","a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b")
m<-seq(1:12)
g<-data.frame(a,b,m)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for here, but the `floor()` function should give you what you need.  You might also look into the [`tidyverse`](http://tidyverse.org/), in general, and [`dplyr`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/), in particular, for data manipulation.

It is not entirely clear what you expect as output - the `b` column differs a bit after merging - did you only want the records that match?  Remove `all.x`,`all.y` parameters if you do not care about unmatched records.  I also presume that renaming your columns may be in order:

```
a <- seq(1:10)
b <- c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a")
f <- data.frame(a, b)

a <- c(1.5, 1.4, 2.3, 2.2, 4.4, 4, 5, 6.6, 9.8, 4.1, 4.6, 5.5)
b <- c("a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b")
m <- seq(1:12)
g <- data.frame(a, b, m)

## floor function takes care of rounding down
g$c <- floor(g$a)

merge(f, g, by.x = "a", by.y = "c", all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)
#> Warning in merge.data.frame(f, g, by.x = "a", by.y = "c", all.x = TRUE, :
#> column name 'a' is duplicated in the result
#>     a b.x   a  b.y  m
#> 1   1   a 1.5    a  1
#> 2   1   a 1.4    b  2
#> 3   2   b 2.3    b  3
#> 4   2   b 2.2    b  4
#> 5   3   a  NA <NA> NA
#> 6   4   b 4.4    a  5
#> 7   4   b 4.0    b  6
#> 8   4   b 4.6    a 11
#> 9   4   b 4.1    b 10
#> 10  5   a 5.5    b 12
#> 11  5   a 5.0    a  7
#> 12  6   a 6.6    b  8
#> 13  7   a  NA <NA> NA
#> 14  8   b  NA <NA> NA
#> 15  9   b 9.8    a  9
#> 16 10   a  NA <NA> NA
```